# SQL Query: Joining 4 tables to one

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried all the similar questions but I can not get what I want.

Need help with Joining the table.

```
1. Table bookings: 
id = 1 customer_id = 1 booking_details = 'venue etc'

2. Table customers: 
id = 1 name = 'John Citizen'

3. Table: booking_objects: 
id = 1 booking_id = 1 object_id = 1
id = 2 booking_id = 1 object_id = 2

4. Table objects: 
id = 1 name = 'Object 1' 
id = 2 name = 'Object 2'
```

I want to join tables to I get "Venue etc, Jhon Citizen, Oject 1, Object 2"

currently I am getting "Venue etc, Jhon Citizen" using below query

```
$this->db->select("bookings.bookig_details, customers.name as customer_name, objects.name as object_name")->join("customers", "customers.id = bookings.customer_id", "left outer")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your requirement, Venue etc, Jhon Citizen, Object 1, Object 2 are mentioned. Object 1 and Object 2 comes under same column i.e, objects.name.

As per my understanding you need booking_details, customer_name, obj_name are your required columns.

```
select b.booking_details, c.name as customer_name, o.name as obj_name 
bookings b
inner join
customers c
on b.customer_id  = c.id
inner join
booking_objects bo
on b.id = bo.id
inner join 
objects o
on bo.object_id = o.id
```

You can change the join types based on your requirement.

Instead of using values of the required output, it would have been better to use required columns in your question for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry is this possible to get result in one row? currently it returns 2 rows with. I want result in 1 row e.g "Venue etc, John Citizen, Object 1, Object 2" but currently i am getting in 2 rows "Venue etc, John Citizen, Object 1" "Venue etc, John Citizen, Object 2"

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can use self join as mentioned in the answer by @D-Shih. But, I think it is not a scalable solutoin. For now, as you have 2 objects, you can self join once. If the same id has n objects, it is not practical to self join n times. 
Still, if you want to show all objects of a particular booking_id in one row, you can use string_aggregate functions which scales and shows the data in one row for one booking_id. [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Self JOIN`

like this.

```
select b.booking_details,c.name 'customer_name',o1.name 'o1Name',o2.name 'o2Name'
FROM objects o1 
 join objects o2 ON o1.id = 1  and o2.id = 2
 join booking_objects bo on o1.id = bo.object_id
 join bookings b on b.customer_id = bo.booking_id
 join customers c on bo.booking_id = c.ID
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/594973/14*